# LSTM Regression - State of the Art

Tags: regression, lstm

i'm trying to review the current state of the art architectures / models generally for **Regression based on LSTM Networks** (x-Sequence to y-Sequence / function approximation).

Basically, what are the most used extensions, starting from the very basic lstm regression network *(input layer, simple lstm layer, fully connected output layer)* ?

So far, I've seen many research papers with Convolutional Layers and Bi-directional layers, e.g.
[Novel Deep Learning Model with CNN and Bi-Directional LSTM for Improved Stock Market Index Prediction](https://doi.org/10.1109/CCWC.2019.8666592).

Comment: Sometimes people add a memory stack with three simple operations (push current hidden state, pop old hidden state, NO OP) to RNNs and they train the network to operate this stack. See https://github.com/isayev/ReLeaSE for an example implementation in pytorch.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I think my basic thought would be: if i would want to do an LSTM Regression, what are my options for layers or generally architectures ? The time when LSTMs have been "invented", the lstm regression models weren't that adavanced. (mostly because of computational resources).

Comment: For regression tasks in research papers, i have an impression that "vanilla" LSTM Layers aren't that common, and new architectures have been proven to be more effective for specific tasks. e.g. **using only bidirectional LSTM** and no basic LSTM layer at all or creating Hybrid models like a combining CNN and LSTM layers.